# MySQL server has gone away error. --max_allowed_packet=2G doesn't work either

Tags: mysql, blob, lampp

I am constantly getting the following error while trying to import a MySQL table.

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 15692: MySQL server has gone away
```

The error occurs when inserting entries of a table with a longblob field. I have tried everything suggested on the internet, like using `--max_allowed_packet`, export and import explicity in `utf8`, exporting in `--hex-blob`, increasing `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` etc, but nothing works!

I dug a bit deeper and noticed that the value of `--max_allowed_packet` isn't being set properly. I am using LAMPP, and in the file `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`, I have the following under the [mysqld] section.

```
max_allowed_packet = 2G
```

However, MariaDB still shows that its value is set to only 1 MB. Why is it like that? I stopped and restarted LAMPP server, but still to no avail. Even setting this parameter from the command line, like as follows, doesnt' work!

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -h localhost --max_allowed_packet=2G -u root -p
```

In both cases, when I query its value, I get the following.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
--------------
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
--------------

+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1048576 |
+--------------------+---------+
```

How can I solve this problem? Note that I am logged in as root.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html the upper limit of max_allowed_packet is 1G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have solved the problem. Shown below, is how I did it.

Inside an MySQL shell (open one by typing`/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -h localhost -u root -p`), set the value of `max_allowed_packet`, like this.

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

After exiting that MySQL shell, this value should have been set. If you now go back to a new MySQL shell, and type the following,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

It displays the correct value, as shown below.

```
+--------------------+------------+
| Variable_name      | Value      |
+--------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------+------------+
```